# PHP getting weekdays, hours and minutes

Tags: php, datetime

What's wrong with my code? I want my script to check if it is Monday and is greater or equal to 22:00 and less than or equal to 23:00.

```
$t = date("D:G:i");

if ($t >= "Mon:22:00" && $t <= "Mon:23:00") {
    $status = "up";
    } else {
    $status = "down";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot compare strings (it is not dates, it is just strings of arbitrary symbols), as we're not code-writing monkeys I'll just describe how you should do it instead of providing copy-pastable code:

1. get weekday number, hour, minute from current time into 3 separate variables
2. compare weekday variable with monday value
3. if weekdays are ok - compare hours with 22
4. minutes can be omitted here, if you check for [22, 23), or you need to make additional comparison for 23:00 case

another approach - generate unix timestamps for the closest monday 22 and 23 hours, and then numeric comparisons

Comment: im so sorry but I did not understand it. I am a newbie in php development :(

Comment: @viclatag it is not about php, it is about general programming, all answers already on this page, try to start from beginning http://norvig.com/21-days.html

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing two strings instead of two numerical values. Not ideal at all. You want to look into converting the dates into a Unix timestamp and comparing those values.

**mktime**: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php

*mktime* will allow you to get a Unix timestamp for any date.

**time**: http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php

*time* will give you the current date and time as a Unix timestamp.

You can then compare to find out which is larger/smaller than the other.